# Create a simple react multi-ternary operator on large scale to merge arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ternary-operator

I'm looking to create a concise multi-ternary operation in React that merges arrays together with different combinations depending on which props exist.

small scale example, I have:

`array3` should always be output.

`array2` should only be merged with `array3` (or `array1`) if `this.props.data.array2` is present.

`array1` should only be merged with `array3` (or `array2`) if `this.props.data.title1` is present.

```
{
  this.props.data.title3
    ? this.props.data.title2
      ? this.props.data.title1
        ? [...array1, ...array2, ...array3]
        : [...array2, ...array3]
      : [...array2, ...array3]
    : [...array3];
}
```

but as there's more combinations, I'd have to produce this more times.

I potentially have 100's of combinations, and I'm looking for a simple way to write this concisely, so I don't have to have to write excessive multi-ternary operators to get the desired output.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: use simple if else instead of ternary in such case

Answer (score 1):

You should use a simple if blocks instead and add the merge the required values to `array3`

```js
this.props = {
  data: {
    title1: true,
    title2: false,
    title3: true
  }
}

let array3 = [3]
let array2 = [2]
let array1 = [1]

if(this.props.data.title2){
  array3 = [...array3,...array2]
}


if(this.props.data.title1){
  array3 = [...array3, ...array1]
}

console.log(array3)
```

***Note:-*** If you want to merge array's for all the title which has truthy values, you can simply create a function which does this merging part and call it for titles, instead of repeating if blocks for each title

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the 3 arrays with another array, and filter the array according to the relevant `title` for sub-array index. Flatten the results:

```js
const props = {
  data: {
    title1: true,
    title2: false,
    title3: true,
  }
}

const array3 = [3]
const array2 = [2]
const array1 = [1]

const output = [array3, array2, array1]
  .filter((_, i, { length }) => props.data[`title${length - i}`])
  .flat()

console.log(output)
```